# How do I properly model / clear observable values in Knockout JS (text area fields are not updating)?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am creating a model in KO to represent and bind to fields on an html form.

The idea being that I could click a button which would insert a default page name (text form field value) and then clear out (insert blank strings) into the other form fields (all text area fields)

To test:

- Fill in a value for each of the form fields
- Press the Add New Page button
- It will insert the default page name value in the first field
- It WILL NOT insert the blank values in the text areas as I would anticipate

What should I be doing differently to properly bind/clear the values related to the textarea fields?

```js
function Page() {
    self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("");
    self.HEADhtml = ko.observable("");
    self.HEADERhtml = ko.observable("");
    self.FOOTERhtml = ko.observable("");
    
    self.initialize = function()
    {
        self.name("New Page");
        self.HEADhtml("");
        self.HEADERhtml("");
        self.FOOTERhtml("");
    }
    
    self.save = function()
    {
        alert('Save Function Placeholder');
    }
}

function koScope()
{
    var self = this;
    
    self.currentpage = new Page();    
}

ko.applyBindings(new koScope());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-block text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" data-bind="click: currentpage.initialize">Add New Page</button>
</div>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pagename" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Page Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input class="form-control" id="pagename" type="text" data-bind="value: currentpage.name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">HTML HEAD</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"  data-bind = "text: currentpage.HEADhtml"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">HTML HEADER</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" data-bind = "text: currentpage.HEADERhtml"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">HTML FOOTER</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" data-bind = "text: currentpage.FOOTERhtml"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group margin-none">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind = "click: currentpage.save">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inputs and textareas you want to use the `value` binding, not the `text` binding.